# Application Loader Error: Launch Path Not Accessible

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, loader

I'm trying to submit an application to Apple but am coming up with an error in Application Launcher.

Once I choose the zip file I hit Send and it comes up with the error:

`Exception while validating: launch path not accessible`

No idea what to do here, can't find much info on it at all on the net.

I have tried reapplying my provisioning / distribution profiles with no luck.  Have re-opened XCode many times in case it was confused.

I submitted the same app a week and a bit ago and it went through fine, it got rejected so I made a few small changes and now this error comes up - no big changes were made.

The only thing I can think of is that I needed to update XCode and the SDK - from xcode_3.2.4_and_ios_sdk_4.1 to xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final as the iPad I am using was updated to 4.2.

Any ideas on where to go from here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should check the read only property of your app folder.

Comment: Looking at the folder it's not "locked", is that what you mean?  Not sure where to look sorry.

Comment: The folder where your app has deployed, is it has all the access permission?

Comment: Hmm I've gotten it working.  It seems while XCode was updating Application Launcher had stayed open.  It must have missed something somewhere as when I restarted it and re-logged in and tried again it worked.  I also did a disk permissions repair in Disk Utility but I don't think that did anything to help this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had same problem, closed App Loader, restarted App Loader, problem solved.